# Django cache loses keys

Tags: python, django, caching, django-cache

I have a Django installation that uses the FileSystem caches. The caching system is used by an array of different views. Putting in place various logs to log when a key is not found in the cache and hence regenerated, I've found out that often the keys are lost. I don't have any "cache delete" in place and all the keys are stored to last 24 hours, but in the logs they all appear to be regenerated once in a while.

Is there any hidden parameter like "don't store more than n keys" or "more than n megabytes of data" or something? I'm a bit lost because it just seems that the keys are lost and I don't know when and why.

Also, I originally chose as cache location "/tmp/django-cache", so I thought that maybe the tmp directory was being cleaned by Linux, but changing the location to a "safer" one in my home directory doesn't change the anomaly.

Also, the full cache directory is around 25Mb, so I don't think there is something cleaning it up because it's too big.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this in production? Do you have multiple servers for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum number of items allowed in the cache before old values are deleted for `locmem`, `filesystem` and `database` backends is 300. You can change it by setting `OPTIONS` > `MAX_ENTRIES`.

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#cache-arguments):

> `MAX_ENTRIES`: The maximum number of entries allowed in the cache before old values are deleted. This argument defaults to `300`.